# How to detect collisions properly?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

This is my first time making a game with LibGDX and I'm trying to increase the score in my game when two things collide, but it doesn't register the collision at all.

This is what I have in the *Player* class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.EdgeShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.mygdx.summative.MyGdxGame;
import com.mygdx.summative.Screens.PlayScreen;

public class Player extends Sprite {

public World world;
public Body b2dbody;
private TextureRegion peteStand;

public Player(World world, PlayScreen screen ){
    super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("goomba"));
    this.world = world;
    definePlayer();
    peteStand = new TextureRegion(getTexture(), 227,1,16,16);
    setBounds(227,1,16/ MyGdxGame.PPM,16/MyGdxGame.PPM);
    setRegion(peteStand);
}

public void update (float dt ){
    setPosition(b2dbody.getPosition().x - getWidth() /2, b2dbody.getPosition().y - getHeight()/2);
}

public void definePlayer (){
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(32 / MyGdxGame.PPM,32 /MyGdxGame.PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2dbody = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(6/MyGdxGame.PPM);

    fdef.shape = shape;
    b2dbody.createFixture(fdef);

    EdgeShape body = new EdgeShape(); // used for collision dectection
    body.set(new Vector2(-1/MyGdxGame.PPM,7/MyGdxGame.PPM), new Vector2(1/MyGdxGame.PPM,7/MyGdxGame.PPM)); // sets up borders for collision on player
    fdef.shape = body ;
    fdef.isSensor = true;
    b2dbody.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("body");   // used to identify collisions to see if one if the player
}

}
```

When cloud hits, I want to increase the score, so I wrote this in the *Object* class:

```
public class Cloud extends InteractiveTileObject {

public Cloud(World world, TiledMap map, Rectangle bounds) {
    super(world, map, bounds);
    fixture.setUserData(this);
}

@Override
public void onBodyHit() {
    Gdx.app.log("Cloud" , "Collision");
    Hud.addScore(200);
}
}
```

What am I missing? This is contact methods in the *ContactListener* class:

```
    @Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {     // when to things start to collide

    // figures out with fixture is which in a collision of two objects
    Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

    // checks of one is players body
    if (fixA.getUserData() == "body" || fixB.getUserData() == "body"){
        Fixture body = fixA.getUserData() == "body" ? fixA : fixB;
        Fixture object = body == fixA ? fixB : fixA;

        // checks if the object the player collided with is a interactive object
        if (object.getUserData() instanceof InteractiveTileObject) {
            ((InteractiveTileObject) object.getUserData() ).onBodyHit();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `fixA.getUserData() == "body"` is wrong because you are comparing the equality of references. To check if a `String` is equal to another in terms of the content, i.e. lexicographically you should do `fixA.getUserData().equals("body")` or a safer way `"body".equals(fixA.getUserData())`.

On a side note, the `"player"` identifier may be more suitable, as technically speaking everything in the physics world is a body.

Comment: would i have to change the inside of the if statement as well?

Comment: You will need to change all statements where you've used "==" to compare two String objects